# Cypress equalIgnoreCase

Tags: mocha.js, chai, cypress

I am using Cypress for testing but I can't find equalIgnoreCase in the documentation.

here is my testing code and I want equalIgnoreCase in this case:

```
cy.get('#SelectedToAddress')
    .select('United Arab Emirates').should('have.value','AE')
```

I found in chai this for equalIgnoreCase

```
chai.assert.match("chrome", /Chrome/i); //should return true
```

But I don't how to use same with value property in Cypress

Also, I found this chai plugin

http://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-string/

But I don't know how could I add a chai plugin to Cypress

Comment: Looking at examples [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/and.html#Yields), I would say `.should('match',/AE/i)`

Comment: @eric99 and what about 'have.value' someone suggest its('value') but it doesn't work

Comment: Not sure I understand the question in your comment. Are you expecting 'have.value' to ignore case? `its('value')` sadly does not work in the way you might expect with a `cy.get()`.

Comment: so how could I use "should" with the value of my element?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can also do this:

```
cy.get('#SelectedToAddress')
  .select('United Arab Emirates')
  .its('value')
  .then($value => {
    let valueRead = $value.toLowerCase();
    expect(value).to.eq(<expected_value_in_lowercase>);
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [invoke](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/invoke.html) command:

```
cy.get('#SelectedToAddress')
    .select('United Arab Emirates')
    .invoke('val')
    .should('match',/^AE$/i)
```